# To call a block in magento home page static block

Tags: php, xml, magento

I want to call a block in content of home page. I am writing a code like that:

```
{{block type='blog/menu_sidebar'  template='latest_blog/latest-blog.phtml'}}
```

But phtml file is not coming in home page.

On the other hand when I call block in layout update xml under under the design tab by writing the code like that :

```
<block type="blog/menu_sidebar" name="right.blog">
    <action method="setTemplate" >
        <template>latest_blog/latest-blog.phtml</template> 
    </action>
<block type="blog/tags" name="blog_tags" />
</block>
```

Then the phtml file is coming in home page.

My problem is that i want to include latest-blog.phtml file in the content of home page because I will have to play with the div structure for designing which i can not play in the layout section.

Comment: Have you tried with block type "core/template" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getLayout() function

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
             ->createBlock("blog/menu_sidebar")
             ->setTemplate("latest_blog/latest-blog.phtml")
             ->toHtml(); ?>
```

This way u can load. if you have any option you can set by calling

`->setCustomOption($optionValue)`

Comment: I have searched a more and upated my question accordingly.Please review that one.